# How to shrink DT datatable without reducing font-size

Tags: r, shiny, dt

The `datatable` in my shiny app looks like this:

[image]

I don't like the scrollbar and think it's not really necessary to have it if I could shrink the table a bit.

I could do it with `div(DT::dataTableOutput("active_cases"), style = "font-size: 75%;")`.
But with my real-world data, it's still a little bit too wide. If I see the yellow marked columns I don't think that there is a need to reduce font size if I could reduce the space between columns.

Is there a way to make such a table more compact/dense?

---

### MWE

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(bslib)

################################################################################
################################ S E R V E R ###################################
################################################################################

server = shinyServer(function(input,output){
  
  output$histogram = renderPlot(
    hist(faithful$eruptions, breaks=input$days_plot)
  )
  
  output$active_cases = DT::renderDataTable(
    mtcars, selection = 'single', options=list(scrollX=TRUE))
  
})

################################################################################
#################################### U I #######################################
################################################################################

ui = shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title="iris test"
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      #h3("Downstream", style="text-align:center; 
      #                        color:white;
      #                        background-color:red'"
      #   ),
      sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
        menuItem("Iris - Active Cases", tabName="active_cases", icon = icon("magnifying-glass-location")),
        menuItem("Iris - Archive", tabName="archive", icon = icon("box-archive")),
        menuItem("Configuration", sliderInput("days_plot", "Days into past", 1, 60, 30))
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName="active_cases", shiny::h2("Active Cases"),
                fluidRow(
                  box(title="Cases", status="primary", solidHeader=TRUE, div(DT::dataTableOutput("active_cases"))),
                  box(title="Cases", status="primary", solidHeader=TRUE, plotOutput("histogram"))
                  )
                ),
        tabItem(tabName="archive", shiny::h2("Archive"))
      )
    )
  )
)

################################################################################
################################### R U N ######################################
################################################################################

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Maybe make the box a bit wider?

Comment: Sure this would work, but then I'm losing space on the right side. If there is really no possibility to make the datatable more dense, I will tweak around like this, but is there really no other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following CSS style:

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(bslib)
library(shinydashboard)

################################################################################
################################ S E R V E R ###################################
################################################################################

server = shinyServer(function(input,output){
    
    output$histogram = renderPlot(
        hist(faithful$eruptions, breaks=input$days_plot)
    )
    
    output$active_cases = DT::renderDataTable(
        DT::datatable(mtcars, selection = 'single', options=list(scrollX=TRUE))
    )
    
})

################################################################################
#################################### U I #######################################
################################################################################

ui = shinyUI(
    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(
            title="iris test"
        ),
        dashboardSidebar(
            #h3("Downstream", style="text-align:center; 
            #                        color:white;
            #                        background-color:red'"
            #   ),
            sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                        menuItem("Iris - Active Cases", tabName="active_cases", icon = icon("magnifying-glass-location")),
                        menuItem("Iris - Archive", tabName="archive", icon = icon("box-archive")),
                        menuItem("Configuration", sliderInput("days_plot", "Days into past", 1, 60, 30))
            )
        ),
        dashboardBody(
            tabItems(
                tabItem(tabName="active_cases", shiny::h2("Active Cases"),
                        fluidRow(
                            tags$style(
                                '
                                #active_cases th {padding: 0;}
                                /* #active_cases :is(th, td) {padding: 0;} */ 
                                '
                            ),
                            box(title="Cases", status="primary", solidHeader=TRUE, div(DT::dataTableOutput("active_cases"), style = "width: 100%")),
                            box(title="Cases", status="primary", solidHeader=TRUE, plotOutput("histogram"))
                        )
                ),
                tabItem(tabName="archive", shiny::h2("Archive"))
            )
        )
    )
)

################################################################################
################################### R U N ######################################
################################################################################

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

To make it more compact, use the second commented line in the style instead `#active_cases :is(th, td) {padding: 0;}`:

[image]